# Why can we connect(Extract data ) only with text and excel files through Tableau Public, but not with Databases like Oracle?

Tags: database, data-analysis, business-intelligence, tableau-api

I can never connect with any database like Oracle through Tableau Public, only text files like excel or csv files are getting connected through Tableau Public for analysis ? Is there any specific reason for that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Tableau Public is Tableau's free offering. I expect that Tableau is able to gain more paying customers by limiting the functionality of Tableau Public. Rightly so in my opinion. Outside of a few variations, like this one, they do keep Public very close to on par with Tableau Desktop functionality.

Comment: ohhk, so is it a guess or you are sure about it ?